# php pdo loop through row skips 1st row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am looping my rows from my database and it works except one thing. it skips the 1st id.
it begins from the second record. any idea how to fix this?
this is my code:

```
<?php
$query = $PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM pokes');
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
?>
<?php
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$n = $row['name'];
$cp = $row['cp'];
echo $id . ' ' . $n . ' ' . $cp . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You're calling `fetch` in advance to throw that data on the ground for a reason, then? PHP is doing exactly what you're asking for here.

Comment: but how do i let it count it from the 1st record?

Comment: Step through the code line by line and think about what PHP is doing here and the problem will become obvious. Hint: `while` executes that statement immediately and will skip to the end of the block if and only if that value is *logically false*.

Comment: What do you mean `count from the 1st record`? I don't see you using the first `$row`..

Comment: @chris85 yes thats the problem i dont know how $row doesnt count from record 1,

Comment: You have `fetch` twice. 1. `$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` 2.  `while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {` so you started at the 2nd row in your `while` loop. The first `$row` is never used.

Comment: No need to add `?><?php` tags between all php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 // your first error is here. You are fetching the first row
 $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
 // And here you start from the second, since you already did ones above
 while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  //...rest of oyur code
 }
?>
```

you have two way to accomplish your task

```
  <?php
  // Just add the PDO::FETCH_ASSOC constant while you are looping
  while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   //...Code here
  }

  // another way is adding the constant before using it 
  $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  while($row = $query->fetch()){
   //...Code here
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

`$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` after `$query->execute();`

just keep the `while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code should be like this:**

```
<?php
$query = $PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM pokes');
$query->execute();
?>
<?php
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$n = $row['name'];
$cp = $row['cp'];
echo $id . ' ' . $n . ' ' . $cp . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't fetch twice for a query.

```
<?php
$query = $PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM pokes');
$query->execute();

foreach ($query as $row) {
$id = $row['id']; $n = $row['name']; $cp = $row['cp'];
echo $id . ' ' . $n . ' ' . $cp . '<br>';
}
?>
```